# PHP isset not showing HTML with ID is set

Tags: php

I have the below section of code and I want to only show the html IF the ID is set in the url.  It isn't working and I am not sure why!  The same code works on other areas of the page just not here!  I am editing some code that someone else built for me, I am a php noob so please bear with me!

Thanks for any help!!

```
<?php if(!isset($_GET['id'])) { ?>      
 <div class="control-group"> Show this text </div>
      <? } ?>
```

Comment: what is the url you are trying?

Comment: Make sure it is a GET and not a POST. As the $_GET global array needs to be set in a GET like @pna is suggesting. Do a var_dump($_REQUEST);die(); $_REQUEST shows the contents of both the $_GET and $_POST global arrays.

Comment: `<?php if(isset($_GET['id'])) { echo  "<div class='control-group'> Show this text </div>"; }; ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your conditional the wrong way round.

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['id'])) { ?>      
 <div class="control-group"> Show this text </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Whoops!  Twat!  Thanks for the help!  It is getting late, that is my excuse!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `not` (`!`), obviously. As the logic you want is `isset` and not `not isset`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['id'])) { 
echo "<div class='control-group'> Show this text </div>"; 
 }; ?>
```

Depending if you want to show the code or not place a ! in front of `isset`.